# Rails - Find similar Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :category

  def self.similar(product)
    where("name LIKE ?", "#{product.name}%").limit(4)
  end
end
```

I would like the self.similar method to product products which are similar to the argument passed to it(product).

The trouble Im having is that this method only returns products which match the argument perfectly.  Im wondering if its possible to set the tolerance of this method to product a broader range of products rather than ones which match the argument perfectly?  Or perhaps another superior way to produce an array of similar products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must simple change your where query to following:

```
def self.similar(product)
  where("name LIKE ?", "%#{product.name}%").limit(4)
end
```

and your LIKE query should work..with the % at the start and the end also not exactly matching results will be returned..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to/can't install a gem, then you can use Postgres' `levenshtein` (if it's installed):

```
Model.select("*, levenshtein(LOWER(name) , '#{thing_name.downcase}') AS fuzzydist").order('fuzzydist ASC').first
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very good experience using [fuzzy_match](https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match). There is no built in ActiveRecord nor Rails nor Ruby support for it otherwise.

So your code would then become more or less

```
require 'fuzzy_match'

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :category

  def self.similar(product)
    fz = FuzzyMatch.new(Product.all, :read => :name)
    return fz.find(product.name).limit(4)
  end
end
```

Comment: i have 150k records, growing 10k every month. if i pluck all, that sounds not so cool to me. how does this scale in big environments?